# C# do while loop start stop

Tags: c#, loops, for-loop, while-loop, do-while

I am trying to make a stop button for this loop but it runs indefinite, nothing happens when i click button 2

```
bool dowhile = false;
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    do
    {
        for (int i = listbox1.Items.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            string textstring = listbox1.Items[i].ToString();
            richTextBox1.AppendText("" + textstring + ": Done\n");
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }
    } while (!dowhile);
}
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.dowhile = true;
}
```

where do i go wrong ?

sry for the "lvlchanger" typo, code is ok now, nothing missing

i'm also looking for a not-so-long fix on this :))

Comment: How are you changing 'lvlchanger'?

Comment: Where exactly are all of the comments/answers finding this `lvlchanger` object? Maybe I'm going blind, but I don't see it in the code and neither does my browser's search. And as best I can tell, the question hasn't been edited to modify the code... Someone care to fill me in?

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. In response to your request for a "not-so-long fix", unfortunately there's no such thing. As my answer explains, a thread cannot do more than one thing at a time. The hacky fix of `DoEvents` is a seriously bad idea for a number of complicated reasons. I would advise no one to use it unless they really understood the issues involved in multi-threading. And if they did, they'd probably use the correct approach instead. Replacing the whole bit with a `BackgroundWorker`, following the sample shown on the MSDN page is definitely the easiest answer, and also the best.

Comment: as i said.. `DoEvents` won't work in this case

Comment: `BackgroundWorker` will make my 4page code, a novel

Comment: Yeah, multi-threading is difficult. Classes like `BackgroundWorker` abstract away much of the difficulty, and make it relatively simple to implement. But that's only "relatively" simple. Nothing is going to change the fact that truly implement multiple threads in your application is difficult. We're still waiting on some enterprising developer to come up with a whiz-bang feature that makes this truly a piece of cake. Right now, we're limited by the technology that we have. I agree it isn't worth it to take the time adding a "Cancel" button for an operation that takes only a short time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Thread.Sleep` is almost always the incorrect approach; when you find yourself wanting to use something like it or `Application.DoEvents` in your code, it's time to take a long step back and think about what you're really doing and why it isn't working. A new design should be in your future.

The real problem here is that you're doing work on the UI thread, which blocks the user from interacting with your application. Your click on Button2 is getting recognized and processed *after* the loop has already finished processing, at which point it does absolutely nothing.

This is because threads can only complete one task at a time. And, in fact, `Thread.Sleep(100)` only makes this worse, because it forces the thread to spin and *do nothing* for 100 milliseconds. That's 100 more milliseconds it will take for the loop to complete for absolutely no gain.

The correct solution to this (common) problem is to spin the loop off onto a separate thread, using something like the [`BackgroundWorker` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx). The MSDN entry has a very good example of its use, including your specific use case: allowing the user to cancel a long-running background task.

Answer (score 5):

The system can't process anything from the message queue (i.e. button clicks, repaints, etc) until your `button1_Click` completes - which it never will. This is *exactly* what causes all those "{blah} is not responding" messages - code that doesn't respond to the message queue promptly.

Basically, don't do that. A ***hacky*** fix would be some `DoEvents()`, but NO! do it properly; basically, handle the event from `button2_Click` instead. Perhaps you should run the refreshes from a timer tick?

Answer (score -1):

Add an `Application.DoEvents()` to the loop to allow the application to process events from other sources.

**/EDIT**
This should work, but...

"This is almost never the correct answer" - Cody Gray

Comment: Think of the kittens! OK, this *will work*, but it is (IMO, and not just limited to me) a very hacky way to do it.

Comment: Yeah I know, lazy answer, I was thinking the accepted answer, but didn't know how to word it. I'll leave this up as a warning...

Answer (score -1):

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    bool dowhile = false;private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
    do 
    {
        for (int i = listbox1.Items.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            string textstring =listbox1.Items[i].ToString();
            richTextBox1.AppendText("" + textstring + ":` `Done\n");
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }
    } while (!lvlchanger && dowhile == false);
}

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.dowhile = true;
}
```

Comment: There's no limit on the number of lines you can use to display your code here. But you'll need to use a different formatting trick: select the entire block, and click the `{}` button in the toolbar. The backticks are only for *inline* code snippets. Cramming everything on one line makes it hard to read, just like a run-on sentence in any language!

Comment: But anyway, what is your answer actually showing us? I can't tell that you've changed anything from the original code.

Comment: changed this line 
while (!dowhile); with
while (!lvlchanger && dowhile == false);